# PHP Output Analysis

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $data="98.8degrees"; 
    (double)$data; 
    (int)$data; 
    (string)$data; 
    echo $data; 
?>
```

I was surprised/confused when the actual output was 98.8 degrees

I thought when $data uses (double), it converts to 98.8.
Then when moving to (int), it becomes 98 and forth
But I guess my analogy is wrong. Can someone explain to me how the output became like that?

Comment: replace (int)$data with $data = (int)$data and it will become an integer. Otherwise you're just casting type but not assigning that value to $data.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
(double)$data; 
(int)$data; 
(string)$data;
```

just return the `double`, `int` and `string` values but they don't change. To change them, you need to do assign the return values to the actual variable like this:

```
$data = (double)$data; 
$data = (int)$data; 
$data = (string)$data;
```

Comment: @Floris that should be a careless mistake

Answer (score 0):

You keep casting it, but turn around and *discard the results*. The value in `$data` never changes. Try the [`settype()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably meant to do was:

```
<?php
    $data="98.8degrees"; 
    $data=(double)$data; 
    $data=(int)$data; 
    echo $data; 
?>
```

If you don't keep the result of your operations, you won't see the result of your operations...

Oh - and I have no idea what you hoped to achieve with the

```
(string)$string;
```

statement, since it's unclear if/how you ever defined `$string`...